# Schema Validation for JSON using Karate

Tags: karate

Good Morning,

I'm just getting started with JSON so I know this is a very basic question, would anyone be able to point out what I'm doing wrong in terms of trying to validation occurrences and problemId below?

```
  Scenario: Get Entity Result with BASIC privledges, return userCanDismiss 'False'
    * def appParams = '{"dhd":{"dhdPermissions":"BASIC"},"podId":"eedev-inta"}}}'
    * def bfToken = TestUtils.getBFTokenWithAppParams(null, 769870979, 0, 'BF_ADMIN', appParams)
    * print 'bfToken -> ', bfToken
    * configure headers = { BFToken: #(bfToken), pod:{"podId":"eedev-inta"} }
    * def schema =
    """
  {
  "data": {
    "ids": [ "#string"
    ]
  },
  "_links":{},
  "_embedded": {
        "validationEventResults": [{
            "data": {
                "validationProblemStats": [{
                        "occurrences": "#ignore",
                        "problemId": "#string"
                }
                ]
            }
        }
        ]
  }
  }
  """

    Given path '/entities/' + externalEntityId + '/types/' + entityType + '/validation-event-results'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response contains schema
```

It seems that the id field is successfully validated but my file fails on trying to validate at occurrences and problemId.

Comment: do you mind editing the question with an example ? if I cannot cut-and-paste your example above quickly into a test and see the problem, I can't help you.

Comment: Hey Peter it has some token validations in the call so I'm not sure if it will run for you, was just curious if how I'm defining occurrences and problemId correctly (to ignore and look for a string). Thanks!

Comment: oh m g. that is much worse than I hoped, I'll make a "guess" answer, and please note the technique where you can define a `response` yourself for the sake of testing. how I wish more people could create simpler questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I have simplified and changed names. Please use this as a reference, read the docs and then find a solution: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation

```
* def stat = { occurrences: '#ignore', problemId: '#string' }
* def eventResult = { data: { validationProblemStats: '#[] stat' } }
* def schema = { embedded: { validationEventResults: '#[] eventResult' } }


* def response = 
"""
{ "embedded": { 
    "validationEventResults": [
      { "data": {
          "validationProblemStats": []
        } 
      }
    ]
  } 
}
"""
* match response == schema
```